# amCharts - Tooltip on links between nodes

Tags: javascript, tooltip, amcharts4

Is it possible to create tooltips for links between nodes on Force-directed tree? Same kind as you rollover nodes.
Using this example:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/force-directed-tree/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use this

```
// You define the ForceDirectedSeries
const networkSeries = chart.series.push(
    new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries()
);
networkSeries.data = nodes;

const linkTemplate = networkSeries.links.template;

linkTemplate.interactionsEnabled = true; // this is so important
linkTemplate.tooltipText = 'tooltip text';
```